# How to do nothing when 1 of the Promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

Hello I am using Promise to update the item and add sale.
What I want is when one of the condition is not true. All the updating and adding sale will not occur.

Here is the code i am using

```
const onFinish = (values) => {

const UpdateItem = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Update the item
        resolve(this.props.updateItem(this.props.item.items, index));
        console.log('items updated')
      })

      const AddSale = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        // Add To Sale
        resolve(this.props.addSale(newSale));
        console.log('sales added')
      })

      const reloadPage = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        reject(new Error('rejected'))
      })

      Promise.all([UpdateItem, AddSale, reloadPage]).then((values) => {
        console.log(values)
      }).catch(error => { 
        console.error(error.message)
      });
}
```

What happening now is. When the function run. The item is being updated. the sale is being made . after that at the last state The promise is rejected.

Even though it is rejected the item and sale changes are already made. I don't want that to occur.
I am using redux to update the items.

Here are the `this.props.updateItem` and `this.props.addSale` code. These are inside different file

```
export const addItem = (item) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // will hit reducer
  Axios.post("/api/items", item, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_ITEM,
        // res.data is new item
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
};

export const addSale = (sale) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // will hit reducer
    // console.log(sale)
    Axios.post("/api/sales", sale, tokenConfig(getState))
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_SALE,
          // res.data is new sale
          payload: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      });
  };
```

Comment: Ciao, the only way I see is a rollback operation on Pormise.all failure. Something like: `Promise.all(...).catch(error => Axios.post("/api/deleteItem", item...)` and the same thing for sales.

Comment: Use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead of `Promise.all()` if you want to know when all the promises are done, even if some are rejected.

Comment: Is it OK for `UpdateItem, AddSale, reloadPage` to be run in parallel or do these need to be run one after the other in sequence?  Your code is currently running them in parallel so `AddSale` does not wait for `UpdateItem` and `reloadPage` does not wait for either of the others.

Comment: Ciao @jfriend00, I dont' know Promise.allSettled but may I ask you some? Suppose that `addSale` post inserts a value into db. Then `reloadPage` comes and reject promise. How could Promise.allSettled rollback the `addSale` post? note: my question is not ironical. It's just to understan how  Promise.allSettled works.

Comment: Please read the page I already linked for [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). It's all right there.  And, it sounds like you don't want to run these operations in parallel anyway, but rather you want to sequence them and then branch your logic based on whether any individual step succeeds or fails.  In that case, you shouldn't be using `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()`.  You should write code that executes one operation, checks if it was successful and then branches in your code based on result.